# Двупроходный Алгоритм Сегментации, неправильный результат

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сегментация

Доброго времени суток!
Писал алгоритм по статье: http://habrahabr.ru/post/119244/
выделяю рамкой нужную область и провожу сегментацию для выбора образца.
Объекты выделяются следующим образом (сегменты подсвечиваются разными цветами):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходный код:

```
    int serialScan(QRect area, std::vector<Data>* points, byte epsilon1, byte epsilon2) {
        int x, y, i, j, L = 0,
                w = area.width(),
                h = area.height();
        bool binA, binB, binC;

        for (y = area.y(); y < area.y() + h; y++) {
             for (x = area.x(); x < area.x() + w; x++) {
                int bx = (x - 1 < area.x()) ? x : x-1,
                    cy = (y - 1 < area.y()) ? y : y-1;

                Data &A = matVecAt<Data>(x , y, _settings::current_image->height(), *points);
                binA = (pixelBrightness(A.pixelInt()) >= epsilon1 && pixelBrightness(A.pixelInt()) <= epsilon2);



                if (!binA) continue;
                Data &B = matVecAt<Data>(bx, y, _settings::current_image->height(), *points);
                Data &C = matVecAt<Data>(x, cy, _settings::current_image->height(), *points);
                B.m = (bx == x) ? 0 : B.m;
                C.m = (cy == y) ? 0 : C.m;


                if (!B.m && !C.m) A.m = ++L;
                else if (B.m  && !C.m) A.m = B.m;
                else if (!B.m &&  C.m) A.m = C.m;
                else if (C.m && B.m) {
                    if (C.m == B.m) A.m = B.m;
//                    else eq_table.insert(std::pair<int, int>(C.m, B.m));
                    else {
                        for (std::vector<Data>::iterator it = points->begin(); it != points->end(); ++it)
                            if (it->m == C.m) it->m = B.m;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return L;
   }
```

Функции доступа к данным и получения яркости (здесь учтены "коэффициенты человеческого глаза") протестированы и работают верно. Как видно на скриншоте на выходе я получаю верно определенный объект но раздробленный, нужно чтобы вся связная область была окашена в один цвет. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что второй проход выполняется в теле цикла первого прохода? Не здесь ли причина некорректности результата?

Comment: Все по статье, там так же, я делал проход по таблице эквивалентности, результаты такие же.код:   http://codepad.org/Jlp4Cupo

Comment: Что здесь делают функции человеческого глаза и зачем они компьютеру?